# How can I send post request to Web Api 2 from Java class

Tags: java, http-post

I want to send data to C# Web Api 2 project from a Java class with post request. But I cannot send it. I tried a lot of ways. While I can send the get request, the result of my post request always returns 404 Not Found. I have configured CORS settings on the server side. My post request is;

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:52729/").path("GetResponse");

DenemeModel model = new DenemeModel();
model.Name = "Cem";

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
try {
    Response response1 = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(model, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    DenemeModel employee = response1.readEntity(DenemeModel.class);
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    System.out.println(employee);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.getLogger(Deneme.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: so is server is up on this port `http://localhost:52729/` on local?

Comment: Yes. http://localhost:52729 is web api service. My Java servlet works on port 8080

Comment: Try to hit that url using postman, i think your url is incorrect

Comment: I tried from postman as a result of the request, lt works. :).But I still can't run Java side.

Comment: What is your response ? :) @Deadpool

Comment: add the postman example also